# Videos on Unit Testing

Tags: .net, unit-testing, presentation

I've been searching for good presentations (slides+audio or video preferred) on Unit Testing but all I seem to find are books and blog posts. The presentation should not be longer than 50 minutes since it will be shown at a brown-bag lunch. General concepts or how to do it on the .NET-platform is what I'm looking for.

Can you recommend a presentation that fits that description?

Comment: There are some good answers on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387326/unit-testing-videos-or-podcasts

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a Powerpoint presentation, here is a 6 part video of Brett L. Schuchert

http://vimeo.com/album/210446

which gives you a live demonstration of unit testing as part of "test driven development". I think you don't need all 6 of them, so you can tailor it to your 50 minutes spec. IMHO very impressive.

Answer (score 1):

I was very, *very* impressed with the [Full Throttle: TDD](http://tekpub.com/view/ft_tdd_wilson/1) video by Rob Ronery and Brad Wilson. It's not free, but it'll be one the best $12 you'll ever spend. The video is a little longer than 50 minutes - I believe it's 65 minutes in total - so maybe you can provide an extra tiny brown bag containing dessert :-)

A snippet from [Rob Conery's blog](http://wekeroad.com/post/8963638411/creatively-thrashing-with-tdd) about the video:

> The premise was that Brad needed to create a subscription billing system that fires off periodic billings and also updates the Customer record - using C# and xUnit.net (Brad’s testing framework he created with Jim Newkirk). To many, this sounds simple. To those that have implemented such a thing - it’s anything but.
>
> The thing that I really, really enjoyed about this episode is that I pushed Brad just enough to remove the “demo veneer” - I gave him a curveball about 30 minutes in where I said “Oh yeah… did I mention that we also do X?” - and he had to adjust.
>
> When you have a mess of tests that assume one thing, then you have to shift to another - it’s a pain in the ass. But Brad handled it amazingly well - taking the opportunity to push more structure into his testing process, then one by one “transition” his old tests into the new approach.
>
> We worked the whole hour inside a single code file - and I’d never seen anyone do that before. Sure, I’ve created a class right there inside the code - but watching Brad spin up class after class, then rename, then delete, then completely restructure his tests… it was very, very interesting.
>
> They always say TDD is a “design process” - yet I’ve never seen it used in a truly “design-y” way - like a painter might toss color after color on a canvas until it looks/feel just right. And that’s exactly how it felt watching him.
>
> About 15 minutes in Brad mentions that “I leave a class in the test file until it’s ready to go public” - meaning that he has enough tests to justify his design decisions. A concept I’d never really thought about before - sort of like using the test file as a bit of a “womb”.
>
> He “felt” his way through the creation of the billing system - talking to himself the whole time and creating something rather interesting and pretty damn close to what we ended up with after close to 3 years being live.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps take a look at James Shore's [Let's Play TDD](http://jamesshore.com/Blog/Lets-Play/) videos. I haven't watched nearly all of them (only just started, actually) but they seem to be good material, working with a chunk of code at a time.